# C++: Why is the error object not thrown if the parentheses are empty?

Tags: c++

I am new to exception handling so i can't understand why in this code if i created an object with the empty parentheses, it doesn't throw the exception object but if i passed parameters to the constructor it works fine. If this has something to do with the type of constructor , can you mention the different types of constructor so i can google them . Thanks in advance.

```
class test {
public:
    class error {};
    test(){
        throw error();
    }
};

int main()
{
    try {
        test p();
    }
    catch(test::error)
    {
        cout <<"Error caught!"<< endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vexing parse with `test p();` (which is function declaration).

Use `test p{};` or `test p;` instead